# Regex неправильно проверяет почтовый индекс

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

У меня возникла проблема с проверкой почтового индекса - он должен состоять ровно из 6-ти цифр, но паттерн `"[0-9]{6}"` реагирует как на неправильный ввод при кол-ве цифр меньше 6-ти, однако пропускает как корректный при любом кол-ве цифр больше 6-ти.
Вот полный код на C#

```
 Console.WriteLine("Введите почтовый индекс в формате 000000");
 string s = Console.ReadLine();
 if (Regex.IsMatch(s, "[0-9]{6}"))
 {
 Console.WriteLine("Почтовый индекс введен корректно");
 }
 else
 {
 Console.WriteLine("Некорректный ввод");
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего нужно переписать регулярку вот так

```
"^[0-9]{6}$"
```

Почему? некоторые движки их добавляют неявно, а некоторые - нет. Данные символы являются "якорями" начала и конца строки.

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло!

Comment: @Nikita Галочка слева помечает ответ как решение